# Preventing garbage collection when bridging C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I am currently taking a C++ codebase and writing managed C++/CLI wrappers to enable C# bridging. One of my managed classes contains an unmanaged block of `malloc`ed memory:

```
public ref class ManagedFoo
{
public:
   ManagedFoo()  { m_fooData = malloc(AmountNeeded); }
   ~ManagedFoo() { free(m_fooData); } // not sure if this should be a finalizer instead
   void *m_fooData;
};
```

A related class holds onto a pointer to that allocated block, and sends it into unmanaged territory, where it is assumed to exist until a particular call is made:

```
public ref class ManagedBar
{
public:
    static void BorrowFooData(ManagedFoo^ f) 
    { 
      TotallyUnmanagedCode(f->m_fooData);
      // The unmanaged code has held onto this pointer for future use
    }
    static void DoneWithFooDataNow() 
    {
      MoreTotallyUnmanagedCode();
      // The unmanaged code is finally done with f->m_fooData at this point
    }
};
```

Used like so:

```
ManagedBar^ b = gcnew ManagedBar;
b->BorrowFooData(myFooA);
b->BorrowFooData(myFooB);
b->BorrowFooData(myFooC);
// lots of other code here, where myFoos could potentially become unreferenced

// at some point in the future...
b->DoneWithFooDataNow();
```

How can I best make this safe from premature garbage collection?

My current workaround feels pretty expensive--I added a `List<ManagedFoo^> keepAlive` object inside `ManagedBar`, and every call to `BorrowFooData` just `Add`s that `foo` to the list. That way, I can be sure that a reference continues to exist and garbage collection can't happen. (`DoneWithFooDataNow` clears the `keepAlive` list.)

I haven't actually stress tested this code enough to see the garbage collector cause an issue but I am sure it's only a matter of time.

Comment: Your code example is too vague to understand what the issue is. You write "could potentially become unreferenced", but what do you mean by that? To keep the object alive, you _do_ need to maintain a reference to it. But what are those variables? Won't they keep the reference? The one possible caveat is that the framework may notice the variables aren't used again and collect the object on that basis. You can use `GC.KeepAlive()` to avoid that. But there's not enough information here to know what answer is correct in _your_ situation.

Comment: I mean the only reference could be inside the "totally unmanaged code" section. This code is part of a widely-used framework and there's no way to predict how it will be called. `BorrowFooData` could be called in one function and `DoneWithFooDataNow` could be called in a completely separate place. `GC.KeepAlive` only works within the duration of a single function so it is not helpful to me; I can't predict when the client code will call `DoneWithFooDataNow` as it is used all over the place.

Comment: _"the only reference could be inside the "totally unmanaged code" section"_ -- I don't see any place in your code example where the _managed_ object reference is passed to _unmanaged_ code. In any case, the bottom line is that if there are no references to the object, it may be collected. You have to keep a reference _somewhere_. If the caller of `ManagedBar` refuses to do it, then I guess a list in that class is as good a way as any. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to really understand the scenario fully.

Comment: That place is `TotallyUnmanagedCode(f->m_fooData);`. This hands off the `foo` internal data to unmanaged code, where the garbage collector can't find it. I could write a standalone example very quickly if you like, but it won't reproduce any problems unless you know of a way to force the garbage collector to aggressively reap everything.

Comment: The internal `m_fooData` object isn't a managed object anyway. Whether the GC could find it or not is irrelevant. You can call `GC.Collect()` to force a collection operation.

Comment: It's 100% relevant because the lifetime of `m_fooData` is directly tied to the lifetime of `ManagedFoo`. It is created when `ManagedFoo` is created and destroyed when `ManagedFoo` is reaped.

Comment: Is there an IDEOne.com equivalent for C++/CLI? I can't find one.

Answer (score 2):

The `GCHandle` class is precisely made for storing a reference in unmanaged code. Its documentation includes examples.

**PS:** To your question, yes, disposing of unmanaged resources should be in a finalizer. And if I remember correctly, if you include a destructor, you should explicitly call the finalizer from the destructor, in case you `Dispose` of the object.

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to maintain a `List<GCHandle>` so that I can `GCHandle.Free` them? Would that be any more efficient than my existing `keepAlive` list?

Comment: Also, can you please explain why the finalizer is correct? I don't understand the subtleties.

Comment: The point of GCHandle is that you can use its `ToIntPtr()` method to store them within unmanaged structures. The kind of unmanaged structures that you pass to your unmanaged code. As for the finalizer/destructor thing, what I remember is: "The destructor is called on Dispose(), the finalizer is called on collection." And the point I'm not 100% sure about (but still think it happens) is that the destructor calls SuppressFinalize() on the object, so you have to call the finalizer from the destructor or it will never be called.